# How to find Check Point firewall version from command line

Tags: firewall, checkpoint

On Check Point firewall's command line, how can I find its version?
Major version, minor version and optionally build number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: all the commands available on clish (default CLI shell) shell, Gaia OS.*

The most basic command is:

```
show version all
```

Example output:

> Product version Check Point Gaia R75.45
>   OS build 123
>   OS kernel version 2.6.18-92cp
>   OS edition 32-bit

---

Other relevant commands from [Check Point CLI reference guide](http://supportcontent.checkpoint.com/documentation_download?ID=11657):

**Security Gateway Version**
Display the Security Gateway major and minor version number and build number:

```
fw ver [-k][-f <filename>]
where:
  -k Print the version name and build number of the Kernel module.  
  -f <filename> Print the version name and build number to the specified file.
```

**VPN Version**
Display the VPN major version number and build number.

```
vpn ver [-k] -f <filename> 
where:   
  ver Displays the version name and version build number
  -k Displays the version name and build number and the kernel build number
  -f Prints the version number and build number to a text file.
```

**Products and the Operating System**
Obtain details of the products and the operating system installed on the specified Check Point Security Gateway, and to update the database.

```
cprinstall get <object name>
where:
  <object name> The name of the Check Point Security Gateway object defined in SmartDashboard.
```

Example:

> cprinstall get gw1
>   Checking cprid connection...
>   Verified
>   Operation completed successfully
>   Updating machine information...
>   Update successfully completed
>   'Get Gateway Data' completed successfully
>
> Operating system Major Version Minor Version
>   SecurePlatform R75.20 R75.20
>
> Vendor      Product          Major Version Minor Version
>   Check Point VPN-1 Power/UTM  R75.20        R75.20
>   Check Point SecurePlatform   R75.20        R75.20
>   Check Point SmartPortal      R75.20        R75.20

**[On SmartCenter] Management Server Version**

```
fwm ver [-f <filename>]
where:
  -f <filename> Exports the build number data to a file
```